# localhost_access log tomcat which time rotate

Tags: tomcat, logging, rotation

I want to rotate tomcat localhost_access file.So,i added server.xml in maxDays=90
and log file removed every day.But,over 93 log file retained in server.
eg.
Today is 2023/08/07
I added maxDays=90 in server.xml
so,2023/05/06 is over 90.
please help me.
I would line to know tomcat running which time.